# Adding ".xml" at the end of custom route path

Tags: routes, 8

I am trying to create custom route which will look like a xml file like this `example.com/my/custom/path.xml` and I am getting NGINX 404, it won't even goes to Drupal.

I tried to research but I could not find anything helpful. Although I found out that if I use other types of extensions it is working, e.g. `example.com/my/custom/path.html` and `example.com/my/custom/path.yml` is returning Drupal response from my custom controller.

I suspect there is some config issue with `.htaccess` or in web-server config but I am not sure yet what is it that prevents `.xml` extension to work in route paths.

Comment: You say you have an nginx webserver. AFAIK nginx doesn't support `.htaccess`. So probably something in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: That is correct, .htaccess is apache related file, not nginx. This must be the config of your nginx which treats xml as a file to return from storage rather than drupal response.

Comment: Yeah, missed that. 

Another thing I found out after your comment is that it works on Apache but not on Nginx. I swapped Nginx container with Apache. I wonder what is the actual config that prevents it working on Nginx.

Comment: have you swapped your web service to  Apache?

Comment: @otarza there's no single nginx config, lots of ways it can be set up so no way to know, but very often it's configured so file paths are served directly from disk. You probably need to change that rule so it doesn't include the xml suffix.

Comment: @Yusef yes, I am using Wodby's Docker4Drupal setup and when I swapped nginx with apache it started to work.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong maybe it's better to find out what kind of default configuration Docker4Drupal has and create pull request there.